# What's the correct way to use Jasmine from Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

After much hacking, I've managed to get a simple Jasmine test running via Node.

However, there is some weird stuff I do not understand... The jasmine files export functions that appear to need a reference to themselves passed back in to work (this goes for both Jasmine and the ConsoleReporter).

I'm certain this isn't the correct way to do this (though I'm happy that I finally made some tests run :)), so can someone explain the better way to do this?

(Note: I'm not interested in pulling in more third party code I don't understand like node-jasmine; I want to understand what I had for now; not add more!)

```
// Include stuff
jasmine = require('../../../Apps/Jasmine/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/jasmine.js');
jasmineConsole = require('../../../Apps/Jasmine/jasmine-standalone-2.0.0/lib/jasmine-2.0.0/console.js')


// WHAT THE? I DON'T EVEN KNOW WHAT THIS MEANS
jasmine = jasmine.core(jasmine);
jasmineConsole.console(jasmineConsole, jasmine)


// Set up the console logger
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmine.ConsoleReporter({ print: console.log }));


// Create some global functions to avoid putting jasmine.getEnv() everywhere
describe = jasmine.getEnv().describe;
it = jasmine.getEnv().it;
expect = jasmine.getEnv().expect;


// Dummy tests

describe("A suite", function() {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
    it("contains spec with a failing expectation", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
    });
});


// Kick off execution

jasmine.getEnv().execute();
```

[image: Jasmine "working"]

**Edit:** Noticed this in the shipped `bootstrap.js`, which is basically the same (other than different naming)... So maybe this is normal?!

[image: It's not just me doing bonkers stuff!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pivatol recently added [better node.js support](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/v2.0.0/release_notes/20.md#better-nodejs-support) to Jasmine in 2.0 and plans to release an official NPM package.  For now you can use it from node by following the implementation used in their own [node test suite](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/spec/node_suite.js).

Here is a brief explanation into what is happening under the covers in the code you wrote:

`jasmine = jasmine.core(jasmine);`  When you initially require('jasmine') you are getting back a single function, getJasmineRequiredObj();  By calling jasmine.core(jasmine), you are tell jasmine to return it's behavioral methods using node `exports` statements instead of adding them onto the window.jasmineRequire object.

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/requireCore.js

```
function getJasmineRequireObj() {
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    return exports;  
  } else {
    window.jasmineRequire = window.jasmineRequire || {};
    return window.jasmineRequire;
  }
}

// jRequire is window.jasmineRequire in a browser or exports in node.
getJasmineRequireObj().core = function(jRequire) {
  var j$ = {};

  jRequire.base(j$);
  j$.util = jRequire.util();
  j$.Any = jRequire.Any();
  ...
  return j$; // here is our jasmine object with all the functions we want.
};
```

`jasmineConsole.console(jasmineConsole, jasmine)` Jasmine initializes it's core functions separately from it's reporters.  This statement is essentially the same thing as jasmine.core(jasmine) only for the console reporter.

https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/console/requireConsole.js

Comment: So are you saying what I've done is the correct way to use this outside of a browser? It looks rather weird like I bodged something!

Comment: I looked at node-jasmine, but it seems to have a load of code in it, and I didn't understand why (seems like Jasmine should support running in node without a lot of work); and I wasn't sure if it was maintained by the Jasmine authors. If this doesn't look bonkers, I'll stick with it for now!

Comment: Looks like the node support is new to 2.0. I expect that all that extra code was needed in 1.3.x https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/v2.0.0/release_notes/20.md#other-changes

Comment: Aha! That page links to https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/spec/node_suite.js which looks like exactly what I couldn't find - a node version of boot.js! I'll switch over to that, should be cleaner! Thanks!

Comment: (possibly worth throwing a link to node_suite.js into your answer to make it easier to find for anyone else that stumbles across this!)

Answer (score 3):

There is also [jasmine-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-node) (that still uses jasmine 1.3 and has a beta version with jasmine 2.0 - February 2015) and [jasmine-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine) (from the jasmine maintainers themselves, with the latest version).

Both of them are easy to use from the command line, with no code required (except the tests, of course!).